# How can I show that these integrals are zero

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can I show that these integrals equal $0$ when $n$ and $m$ are both integers and $n \neq m$?
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(mx)\sin(nx)dx = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(mx)\cos(nx)dx = 0$$
I'm able to show that $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(mx)\cos(nx)-\sin(mx)\sin(nx) dx =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos[(m+n)x]dx = 0$$
So I just need to show that either of the two integrals are zero. Thanks for any help.

Comment: we can use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let : 
$$\eqalign{
  & A = \int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {\sin (mx)\sin (nx)} dx  \cr 
  & B = \int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {\cos (mx)\cos (nx)} dx \cr} $$

Then :
$$\left\{ \matrix{
  B + A = \int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {\cos [(m - n)x]} dx = 0  \cr 
  B - A = \int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {\cos [(m + n)x]} dx = 0 \cr}  \right. \to A = B = 0$$

Answer (score 5):

$$
\cos A \cos B = \frac12(\cos (A+B) + \cos (A-B) )
$$
and remember you need $m \ne n$

Answer (score 3):

Just evaluate the definite integral of: $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos[(m+n)x]dx$$

You'll get:
$$\frac{1}{m+n}*sin[(m+n)x]\Big|_{-\pi}^{\pi} = \frac{1}{m+n}*(sin[(m+n)*\pi]-sin[(m+n)*-\pi])$$

What can you say about this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try using product to sum formulae.

$\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b)=2 \sin a \sin b$ and $\cos(a+b)+ \cos(a-b)=2\cos a \cos b$

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample: $n=1$, $m=-1$,
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\,\cos(mx)\cos(nx)\,dx = \pi$$

Comment: So, the integers $m,n$ should be assumed nonnegative.